# Complex htaccess subfolder 301-redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have a little problem with htaccess redirection, I have an issue which i can't figure out.

- www.old.com/sub should direct to: www.new.com/page/

BUT

- all the **sub**pages of www.old.com/sub (www.old.com/sub/1, www.old.com/sub/2), should redirect to www.new.com/category/1, www.new.com/category/2 etc. (insted of page)

But how?

What I tried (i assumed this should work, but it didn't):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub/$ http://www.new.com/page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sub(/.*)?$ http://www.new.com/category/$1 [R=301,L]
```

note; it is part of a large list of redirections, so it should not affect other redirections in this htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That work with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub/?$ http://www.new.com/page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sub/(\d+)/?$ http://www.new.com/category/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can change `(\d+)` to `(.+)` if you do not use numbers only after `sub/`

Comment: It did the job! Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help a little.